# Rails 3.1 ActionMailer Custom Template Path?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Is it possible to customize the template path for Rails 3.1 ActionMailers? By default, Rails looks in:

```
/app/views/[mailer_class]
```

for the mailer view templates. However, I'd much rather organize them in:

```
/app/mailers/views/[mailer_class]
```

or at least:

```
/app/views/mailers/[mailer_class]
```

I know this was possible in 2.3 via ActionMailer's `template_path` config parameter, but that seems to be deprecated as of Rails 3. Is this kind of customization no longer possible?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This sort of customization is possible still.  There is a couple different ways to do this depending on how your mailers are written.

If you have the format blocks such as format.html you can pass render '/path/to/template'.

Or if you are just calling mail() there are two options for setting the path and template name, which you should just need to pass the path option:

```
mail(:template_path => 'mailers/[mailer_class]', :template_name => '[mailer_method]')
```

You should check out the Rails Guides for more detailed info.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#mailer-views

Comment: I had seen the docs, but I hadn't figured out that template_path was relative to /app/views. Thanks!